# fgets in a loop repeats data in the 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to get my 9x9 grid of numbers from a file and store it in a 2D int array. For this, I wrote my code so that it uses `fgets()` from the file and then converts the char array values to an int and then stores it in that respective spot in the array.

While I thought it was working, when I printed out the array, I noticed how it has repeated values (from the previous row that it read) and it doesn't print out the full 9x9 grid. Here is what I mean:

```
 int strIndex = 1; // Goes every odd to extract number

   /* Need to do this for the whole grid */
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        fgets(str,19, f);
        strIndex = 1;
        // printf("%s\n", str);
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            // Since asci digits start at 48, subtracting gets you the num
            grid[i][j] = (int) str[strIndex] - 48; 
            strIndex = strIndex + 2;
        }
    }
```

This is what I am supposed to be getting (basically whatever is in `input.txt`):

```
 8 2 7 1 5 4 3 9 6 
 9 6 5 3 2 7 1 4 8 
 3 4 1 6 8 9 7 5 2 
 5 9 3 4 6 8 2 7 1 
 4 7 2 5 1 3 6 8 9 
 6 1 8 9 7 2 4 3 5 
 7 8 6 2 3 5 9 1 4 
 1 5 4 7 9 6 8 2 3 
 2 3 9 8 4 1 5 6 7
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
8 2 7 1 5 4 3 9 6 

-38 2 7 1 5 4 3 9 6 

9 6 5 3 2 7 1 4 8 

-38 6 5 3 2 7 1 4 8 

3 4 1 6 8 9 7 5 2 

-38 4 1 6 8 9 7 5 2 

5 9 3 4 6 8 2 7 1 

-38 9 3 4 6 8 2 7 1 

4 7 2 5 1 3 6 8 9
```

Am I using `fgets()` correctly? And what is -38? I can't seem to understand why that is being printed instead of the actual number. (For ex: Instead of 8 from `grid[0][0]`, it prints -38 in `grid[0][1]`. In `fgets`, I made the space `19` because I noticed how `fgets()` also takes in whitespace, so that's why my `strIndex` is incrementing every 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fgets(str,19, f)
```

That doesn't read the whole line. Your lines have 19 **visible** characters but there is a newline (`\n`) character at the end of each line. By reading only 19 characters you leave the newline for the next `fgets`. Hence every second `fgets` call will read a single newline character with the rest of the buffer retained from the previous line. The newline ascii value is `10` and that is where the `-38` comes from since the code does `str[strIndex] - 48`.

So the fix would be to read `20` characters rather than `19`. In fact, it wouldn't hurt to put an even larger buffer. Say `32` bytes. `fgets` will stop at the newline anyway.

Comment: I didn't know `\n` made the count 20. Next time, I'll use more space. Great explanation! Thank you!

Comment: No problems. One more thing I meant to mention: It is best practice to use `'0'` rather than `48` as it makes it much clearer what that line is doing.